# husky pre-commit hook not triggered

Tags: git, git-commit, pre-commit-hook, husky, git-husky

I have set up husky pre-commit hook. I decided to follow version 4.3.8 as I have previously used it.

I have added this to my package.json"
 `"lint-staged": {     "*": "yarn run typecheck"   },  "husky": {     "hooks": {       "pre-commit": "lint-staged",     }   }`

When I run yarn lint-staged then typecheck gets triggered correctly, but nothing happens when I commit anything.
Any ideas what might be going wrong?

I expected husky pre-commit hook to get triggered but nothing happened instead.